# Can't run Corona game on landscape mode

Tags: coronasdk

Running corona game on landscape mode will scale the images as they are portrait ...

in config.lua setting I put

display.contentHeight == 320
display.contentWidth == 480

Answer (score 0):

Corona does NOT automatically change scale, positon etc, of images in your scene to adapt to the change in orientation. You must write code to handle the orientation change.

I couldn't find any official docs that provide a tutorial regarding this topic but I did find a helpful YouTube Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKJs9kCxz48

I'm sure there are other helpful videos available too.

Helpful link about orientation change events: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/orientation/index.html

Comment: Hello @Mathmod71 If I have answered your question please mark the question as correct. If not please add more detail to your question!